# JSF getRowData on nested element in data table

Tags: jsf-2

I'm working on an application in JSF to manage trips made by the people in the various offices in my company.
(i'll try to keep the code at the minimum necessary)

I have an object Trip, an object Office, and a helper object OfficeWithTrips:

```
public class Trip {
    private BigDecimal id;
    private BigDecimal officeId;        
    // getters and setters
}

public class OfficeWithTrips {
    private Office office;
    private DataModel<Trip> trips;
    // getters and setters
}
```

The application has two pages: one where each manager sees the offices he has to manage and the trips of each office, and another with the detail of a single trip.

I have a session bean that contains the list of offices with their trips:

```
public class TripsListBean implements Serializable {
    private DataModel<OfficeWithTrips> officesWithTrips;    
    private Trip currentTrip = new Trip();
    // getters and setters
}
```

On the main page I go through the "offices" in the bean, which has a nested list of Trips. Each office table with its list of trips has a footer with an "add new trip" button.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{tripsListBean.officesWithTrips}" var="officeWithTrips">           
    <h:column>
        <h:form id="tripForm">
            <h:dataTable value="#{officeWithTrips.trips}" var="trip">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Trips for the office: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{officeWithTrips.office.name}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <h:commandButton value="Add new trip"
                        action="#{tripsHandler.addTrip}" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Trip date</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{trip.date}">
                        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </h:column>
                // other columns
                <h:column>
                    <h:commandButton value="edit"
                            action="#{tripsHandler.editTrip}">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{tripsHandler.currentTrip}"
                                value="#{trip}" />
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

When I click "add new trip" I want to be able to set the office id in the trip. What I do in "addTrip()" method is this:

```
public String addTrip() {
    OfficeWithTrips officeWithTrips = tripsListBean.getOfficesWithTrips().getRowData();
    Trip trip = new Trip();
    trip.setOfficeId(officeWithTrips.getOffice.getId());   
    tripsListBean.setCurrentTrip(trip);
    return TRIP_DETAIL_URL;
}
```

My problem is that in addTrip the index in officesWithTrips is always 0, when I want to add a trip to the second office in the list it doesn't work (it always returns the first office).

Can anyone spot the error? I *guess* that when I click the "add new trip" button, this sets the index in the officeWithTrips.trips dataModel, but not in tripsListBean.officesWithTrips...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with another setPropertyActionListener: I added an `Office currentOffice` to `TripsListBean` and set that with a `setPropertyActionListener` directly on the jsf page. Basically, the same I do for `currentTrip`